# How to set code in attributes if its a taghelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

if i make a select & option tags, then visual studio will render it purple, marking it a **taghelper**.

But then i cant put in custom attributes with code like this:

[image]

Its red, but the **@** should be yellow, and the **foo** should be normally black.

When i run it, the first option should have the attribute called data-foo, but it doesn't exist.

But when put code inside a script tag that is drawed purple, then it works, like this:

[image]

Here, it has the normal color, and when i run it and look in developer tools, i can see the **data-foo** attribute in the dom.

However, if i put the **@foo** code at the end, then it doesn't work, similar to option, like this:

[image]

So, is this a bug or what is going on?

I also tried to put to **@foo** at the beginning of the **option** tag, but it still draws it red.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve other than color?

Comment: Well, right now, i just want to put an attribute on it from a string variable. And that string variable is not constant, and could change depending on some code. In my example, the string is constant, but it was just to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's currently possible to use @ syntax to specify an attribute name in a tag helper.  However, you can use @ syntax to specify an attribute value like so:

```
@{
     string fooValue = "someValue";
 }


 <select>
    <option value="red" data-foo="@fooValue">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
 </select>
```

and it color codes accordingly:

[image]